# mongo using temps in aggregations

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have some flight data in json of this format:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"587d12881603f94800054dc5"},"flight_date":{"$date":"2015-08-23T00:00:00.000Z"},"flight_number":863,"destination_city":"    Baltimore, MD","delay_in_minutes":0.0,"cancelled":0.0}
```

I'm trying to do is find the month with the highest ratio of cancelled flights. The code I have groups the cancelled flights by month and divides each of them by the total number of flights for the year. What I want to do is divide the cancelled flights for each month by the total flights for that month (cancelled and not cancelled)  so i get the proper ratio.

```
var size = db.flights.count();
db.flights.aggregate(
[
  {
    $project: {
             cancelled_flights: { $eq: [ "$cancelled", 1 ] },
             month: { $substr: [ "$flight_date", 5, 2 ] },
       }
  },
  {
$match: {"cancelled_flights" : false}
  },
  {
$group: {
        _id : "$month",
        total : {$sum : 1 },
}
  },
  {
       $project: {
              Total_Cancelled : "$total",
              Ratio : { $divide: [ "$total", size] } 
}
  },
         {$sort: {"Ratio":-1}},
         { $limit : 1 }

])
```

I am just learning mongo so please point out my mistakes and I'll fix them.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the sum of canceled flights and non canceled flights in the same $group using $cond statements

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$month",
        total: { $sum: 1 },
        total_canceled: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['cancelled_flights', true] }, 1, 0] } }
        total_non_canceled: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['cancelled_flights', false] }, 1, 0] } }
    }
},
```

$cond statements work like $cond: [condition, if True, if False]

so above you would have sum 'if matches cond', 1, if not, 0

you could then use those results to further process the info how you choose

The group abive would give you tital number of flights, total number of canceled flights, and total number of non-canceled flights all in 1 $group statement.